# Windows Service or Console Application to send email on reminder date from a SQL Server database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, email

I am trying to do the following, the user is filling an issue date and a due date on aspx page. These dates are in `yyyy/MM/dd` format saved in the database.

I would like to be able to send an email to the users before 3 days of the due date.

The methods I was able to find is either using a `Windows Service` or `SQL Job`, but the problem is that I am not able to wrap around the concept and get it working.

The confusing part is that I have to create a new Project for Windows Service, now I don't know if this is right but my approach was to connect to SQL Server and query the database with the issue and due date and then perform the calculation and store it in `resultdate`, if the `resultdate` equals to `Today's date` then send the email to the following users or else don't poll.

---

**EDIT:**

I am trying to achieve the above by creating a `Stored Procedure`, which will be set in the `Windows Service`. Currently, I am struggling with the following:

I have a `MS SQL DB` that contains a `closing date` and the goal is to send an email to users whose emails are in another DB before `2 days` of the `closing date`.

Please see the following code, I am using `CURSOR FOR` but not sure how to use 2 set of commands to `SELECT` different DB, while the first `SELECT` is stored in some variables, and these variables retrieve the balance data from the other DB.

```
USE ROG
DECLARE @Currentdate varchar(10), @DueDate varchar(10), @Serial_No int, @Product_Line varchar(50), @Email varchar(50)
SET @Currentdate = GETDATE()

DECLARE RFQDate CURSOR FOR

SELECT Serial_No, RFQ_Closing_Date, Product_Line FROM RFQDB WHERE DATEDIFF(day, GETDATE(), RFQ_Closing_Date) = 2

OPEN RFQDate

FETCH NEXT FROM RFQDate INTO @Serial_No, @DueDate, @Product_Line 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN 

FETCH NEXT FROM RFQDate INTO @Serial_No, @DueDate, @Product_Line

PRINT ' Due Date ' + @DueDate + ' Serial No ' + coalesce(Convert(varchar(4), @Serial_No),'') + ' Product Line ' + @Product_Line 

END

DECLARE EMAIL CURSOR FOR     --Not sure if this way is correct (this is where I need help!!!

SELECT Sales_Email_ID FROM ProductLineDB WHERE Product_Line = @Product_Line

OPEN EMAIL

FETCH NEXT FROM EMAIL INTO @Email

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN 

FETCH NEXT FROM EMAIL INTO @Email

PRINT ' EMAIL ' + @Email

END

CLOSE EMAIL

DEALLOCATE EMAIL

CLOSE RFQDate

DEALLOCATE RFQDate
```

However, if you test the above code it will correctly show all the due dates but only show 1 email associated with the due dates. Instead it should show 5 emails.

**MS SQL Messages Screen**

```
Due Date 2013/02/14 Serial No 1015 Product Line Tubes
Due Date 2013/02/14 Serial No 1015 Product Line Instrumentation
Due Date 2013/02/14 Serial No 1015 Product Line Tooling
Due Date 2013/02/14 Serial No 1015 Product Line Tooling
Due Date 2013/02/14 Serial No 1015 Product Line Tooling
EMAIL xxx@abc.com
```

**Edit Correct Code**

The following code is fetching all the information I require, now I just need to implement the `sp_send_dbmail` to fetch the `@recipients` from the `@Email` scalar value.

```
The working code is as the following:

USE ROG
DECLARE @Currentdate varchar(10), @DueDate varchar(10), @Serial_No int, @Product_Line varchar(50), @Email varchar(50)
SET @Currentdate = GETDATE()

DECLARE RFQDate CURSOR FOR

SELECT Serial_No, RFQ_Closing_Date, Product_Line FROM RFQDB WHERE DATEDIFF(day, GETDATE(), RFQ_Closing_Date) = 2

OPEN RFQDate

FETCH NEXT FROM RFQDate INTO @Serial_No, @DueDate, @Product_Line 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN 

DECLARE EMAIL CURSOR FOR

SELECT Sales_Email_ID FROM ProductLineDB WHERE Product_Line = @Product_Line

OPEN EMAIL

FETCH NEXT FROM EMAIL INTO @Email

PRINT ' EMAIL: ' + @Email

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN 

FETCH NEXT FROM EMAIL INTO @Email 

END

CLOSE EMAIL

DEALLOCATE EMAIL

FETCH NEXT FROM RFQDate INTO @Serial_No, @DueDate, @Product_Line

PRINT ' Due Date: ' + @DueDate + ' Serial No: ' + coalesce(Convert(varchar(4), @Serial_No),'') + ' Product Line: ' + @Product_Line 

END

CLOSE RFQDate

DEALLOCATE RFQDate
```

Comment: You are storing the date as a string?  Store it as a Date or DateTime, then you will be able to do date math on it.

Comment: @SteveWellens Thanks for your response, but the question is not about the math instead it is how to achieve the end goal. So far I have no problem on acquiring the date by using 

`Select Serial_No, RFQ_No, RFQ_Issue_Date, RFQ_Closing_Date FROM RFQDB WHERE DATEDIFF(day, RFQ_Issue_Date, RFQ_Closing_Date) <=3`

Comment: So you are not storing your dates as strings.  Your question was a bit misleading/confusing since dates in a database do not have a format like 'yyyy/MM/dd'.  Dates in a database can be formatted anyway you choose.  And you included this information that has nothing to do with your underlying question.

Comment: Based on the above, you're almost there. Your query's date math should compare `due date` and `getdate()`. Your result set will be those you send emails to. You can do a simple console app and use Windows Task Scheduler to run it daily/whatever schedule you deem fit.

Comment: @EdSF I think my question is a bit unclear. I am confused on the part if I will use `Windows Service`, I have to link to my database where the `due date` is located and then write the `IF statement` for sending the email?

Comment: Why do you think it matters whether it is a Windows Service or whether it is a Console application?

Comment: You can connect to your db, run queries, obtain result set/s, build and send email either way (console or service).

Comment: @JohnSaunders I don't care whether it is the Windows Service or Console App. Why is everyone interpreting my question wrong. This is not my question whether to use Windows Service or Console App.... Please read my edited post.

Comment: One reason is that your title says "Windows Service". If it doesn't matter, then it shouldn't be in the title.

Answer (score 0):

The working code is as the following:

```
USE ROG
DECLARE @Currentdate varchar(10), @DueDate varchar(10), @Serial_No int, @Product_Line varchar(50), @Email varchar(50), @RFQ_No bigint, @Subject nvarchar(500), @Profile_No int, @Body nvarchar(500), @copy_recipients varchar(max) = 'abc@xyz; dfg@xyz'
SET @Currentdate = GETDATE()

DECLARE RFQDate CURSOR FOR

SELECT Serial_No, RFQ_No, RFQ_Closing_Date, Product_Line FROM RFQDB WHERE DATEDIFF(day, GETDATE(),       RFQ_Closing_Date) = 2

OPEN RFQDate

FETCH NEXT FROM RFQDate INTO @Serial_No, @RFQ_No, @DueDate, @Product_Line 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN 

DECLARE EMAIL CURSOR FOR

SELECT Profile_No, Sales_Email_ID FROM ProductLineDB WHERE Product_Line = @Product_Line

OPEN EMAIL

FETCH NEXT FROM EMAIL INTO @Profile_No, @Email

PRINT ' EMAIL: ' + @Email + ' | Profile No: ' + coalesce(Convert(varchar(4), @Profile_No),'')

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN 

FETCH NEXT FROM EMAIL INTO @Profile_No, @Email 

END

CLOSE EMAIL

DEALLOCATE EMAIL

FETCH NEXT FROM RFQDate INTO @Serial_No, @RFQ_No, @DueDate, @Product_Line

SET @Subject = ' Profile No: ' + coalesce(Convert(varchar(4), @Profile_No),'') + ' | RFQ No: ' +  coalesce(Convert(nvarchar(10), @RFQ_No),'') + ' | Due Date: ' + @DueDate 

SET @Body = 'The following ' + ' RFQ No: ' +  coalesce(Convert(nvarchar(10), @RFQ_No),'') + ' is due on date: ' + @DueDate 

PRINT ' Due Date: ' + @DueDate + ' | Serial No: ' + coalesce(Convert(varchar(4), @Serial_No),'') + ' | Product Line: ' + @Product_Line 

PRINT @Body

PRINT @Subject

IF @Email != ''
BEGIN
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = '31BM',
@importance = 'High',
@recipients = @Email,
@copy_recipients = @copy_recipients,
@subject = @Subject,
@body = @Body;
END
ELSE
PRINT 'No Email to send'
END

CLOSE RFQDate

DEALLOCATE RFQDate
```

The above is the final working code, and I have decided to use `SQL SERVER AGENT` to perform this job per day.

I hope it helps.